# Is there a way to disable snapshots of flows?

Tags: flowground

I am trying to build a flow which regularly gets every JIRA Ticket from my JIRA instance as input data. This works fine however only the first time the flow runs because it saves the retrieved tickets in its snapshot. When I run the flow the second time flowground will not retrieve any JIRA Tickets because they were already retrieved in the first execution. Is there a way to disable this behavior in flowground so that it will retrieve all of the tickets again in the subsequent runs?

Comment: Idea: add a previous step where you overwrite the content of the snapshot object.

Comment: @SebastianLang could you elaborate a bit more on that? How can I do this?

Comment: In the step previous to the JIRA connector, you could try to use, e.g. the NodeJS connector, to emit a new snapshot and by that, overwriting the current value.

https://support.elastic.io/support/solutions/folders/14000112651

Comment: Another idea for a work-around: https://api.flowground.net/docs/v2/#remove-snapshot-for-one-step-in-flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just tested the idea to manipulate the snapshot before the connector is executed.
There is a API function for CRUD operations on snapshots. But you cannot edit a snapshot that is owned by a already started flow. You will get an error message in this case:

> {"errors":[{"detail":"Can not edit snapshot in started flow","status":409,"code":409,"title":"Conflict",....

So you are able to reset the snapshot **before** you start the flow only...but this won't really help you...
I do not see another way beside changing the connectors behavior.

Comment: Just deployed a new version of the JIRA connector, that has a new trigger "GetAllIssues", that ignores the Snapshot.